# Retrieve two GET parameters from a url and echo out in PHP

Tags: php, url, foreach, get

I have a form with multiple checkboxes and hidden inputs, which I'm passing to a second page using GET.
I'm then trying to retrieve the value of each checkbox and the input in a loop and echo out the combined value.

HTML:

```
<form action="criteria.php" method="GET">
<input name="id[]" type="hidden" value="<? echo $criteria_id; ?>" />
<input type="checkbox" name="checked[]" class="checkbox-md" id="<? echo $criteria_id; ?>" value="Y">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-lilac" role="button">Complete</button>
</form>
```

PHP:

```
$criteria_id = $_GET['id']; //get all criteria id
$criteria_checked = $_GET['checked']; //get checked criteria id
foreach($criteria_id as $id) //get id of all checkboxes {
    echo "<BR>Criteria = ".$id."Checked = ".$criteria_checked; //returns id + array?
    if ($checked='Y')//check if checked {
        echo "<BR>Criteria =".$id." Checked = Y";
    } else {
        echo "<BR>Criteria =".$id." Checked = N";
    }
}
```

Comment: and your form does use method GET?

Comment: Can you show your form?

Comment: @LarsStegelitz yes of course.

Comment: @Marty1452 updated OP.

Comment: And what is your question ?

Comment: @MaxMuster see my update below...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to make sure that the inputs have matching array keys:

```
<input name="id[0]" type="hidden" . . .
<input name="checked[0]" type="checkbox" . . .

<input name="id[1]" type="hidden" . . .
<input name="checked[1]" type="checkbox" . . .
```

Depending on how you create these you could use the `$criteria_id`:

```
<input name="id[<? echo $criteria_id; ?>]" type="hidden" . . .
<input name="checked[<? echo $criteria_id; ?>]" type="checkbox" . . .
```

This way the `id` and `checked` array keys will match.  All hidden inputs will be passed from the form but only the checked checkboxes, so check if the key of the `id` is set in the `checked` array:

```
foreach($_GET['id'] as $key => $id) {
    if (isset($_GET['checked'][$key])) {
        echo "<BR>Criteria =".$id." Checked = Y";
    } else {
        echo "<BR>Criteria =".$id." Checked = N";
    }
}
```

Comment: after testing, this is NOT working as expected. The else clause works ok, but the if clause doesn't. If no check boxes are checked, N shows for all, whereas, if any checkbox is checked the echo ids show in order of the GET parameters NOT the id of the checkboxes. 
For example, if I check box 1, 3, 5, ids 1,2,3, are echo'd.

Comment: Thanks - now working as expected! Makes sense that the `id` needs to match in the `get` url!